# What is the best practice to pass object references between two queues with CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I am facing a decision to be made for an applications architecture design.

The Application uses CoreData to persist user information, the same information is also stored on a remote server accessible by a REST-Interface. When the Application starts I provide the cached information from CoreData to be displayed, while I fetch updates from the server. The fetched information is persisted automatically as well.

All of these tasks are performed in background queues as to not block the main thread. I am keeping a strong reference to my `persistenContainer` and my NSManagedObject called `User`.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) User *fetchedLoggedInUser;
```

As I said the User is populated performing a fetch request via

```
[_coreDataManager.persistentContainer performBackgroundTask:^(NSManagedObjectContext * _Nonnull context) {
        (...)
        NSArray <User*>*fetchedUsers = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchLocalUserRequest error:&fetchError];
        (...)
        self.fetchedLoggedInUser = fetchedUsers.firstObject;
        //load updates from server
        Api.update(){
            //update the self.fetchedLoggedInUser properties with data from the server
            (...)
            //persist the updated data
            if (context.hasChanges) {

            context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
            NSError *saveError = nil;

            BOOL saveSucceeded = [context save:&saveError];

            if (saveSucceeded) {

                //notify the App about the updates
                //**here is the problem**
            }
        };
}];
```

So the obvious thing about this is, that after performing the backgroundTask, my `self.fetchedLoggedInUser` is not in memory anymore, because of its weak reference to the NSManagedObjectContext provided by the `performBackgroundTask()` of my PersistentContainer.
Therefore, if I try to access the information from another Model, the values are `nil`.
What would be the best practice to keep the fetched ManagedObject in Memory and not have to fetch it again, every time I want to access its values?

**A)** In the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH24-SW1), Apple suggests using the `objectID` of an ManagedObject, to pass objects between queues
Passing References Between Queues

> NSManagedObject instances are not intended to be passed between
>   queues. Doing so can result in corruption of the data and termination
>   of the application. When it is necessary to hand off a managed object
>   reference from one queue to another, it must be done through
>   NSManagedObjectID instances.
>
> You retrieve the managed object ID of a managed object by calling the
>   objectID method on the NSManagedObject instance.

The perfectly working code for that situation would be to replace the `if(saveSucceeded)` Check with this Code:

```
if (saveSucceeded) {

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSError *error = nil;
      self.fetchedLoggedInUser = [self.coreDataManager.persistentContainer.viewContext existingObjectWithID:_fetchedLoggedInUser.objectID error:&error];
      (...)
      //notify the App about the updates
   });
}
```

But I think this may not be the best solution here, as this needs to access the mainContext (in this case the persistentContainer's `viewContext`) on the mainQueue. This is likely contradictory to what I am trying to do here (performing on the background, to achieve best performance).

My other options (well, these, that I came up with) would be

**B)** to either store the user information in a Singleton and update it every time the information is fetched from and saved to CoreData. In this scenario I wouldn't need to worry about keeping the NSManagedObject context alive. I could perform any updates on a private background context provided by my persistentContainer's `performBackgroundTask` and whenever I'd need to persist new / edited user information I could refetch the NSManagedObject from the database, set the properties, save my context and then update the Singleton. I don't know if this is elegant though.

**C)** edit the getter Method of my `self.fetchedLoggedInUser` to contain a fetch request and fetch the needed information (this is probably the worst, because of the overhead when accessing the database) and I am not even sure if this would work at all.

I hope that one of these solutions is actually best practice, but I'd like to hear your suggestions why/how or why/how not to handle the passing of the information.

**TL:DR;** Whats the best practice to keep user information available throughout the whole app, when loading and storing new information is mostly done from backgroundQueues?

PS: I don't want to fetch the information every time I need to access it in one of my ViewControllers, I want to store the data on a central knot, so that it is accessible from every ViewController with ease. Currently the `self.fetchedLoggedInUser` is a property of a singleton used throughout the application. I find that this saves a lot of redundant code, using the Singleton makes loading and storing the information clearer and reduces the access count to the database. If this is considered bad practice I'd be happy to discuss about that with you.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `NSFetchedResultsController` - they are very efficient and you can use them even for one object.  A FetchedResultsController does a fetch once and then monitors core data for changes.  When it changes you have a callback that it has changed. It also works perfectly for ANY core-data setup. So long as the changes are propagated to the main context (either with `newBackgroundContext` or `performBackgroundTask` or child contexts or whatever) the fetchedResultsController will update.  So you are free to change your core-data stack without changes your monitoring code.

In general I don't like keeping pointers to ManagedObjects.  If the entry is deleted from database then the managedObject will crash when you try to access it.  A fetchedResultsController is always safe to read `fetchedObjects` as it tracks deletions for you.

Obviously attach the `NSFetchedResultsController` to the viewContext and only read it from the main thread.

Comment: Sounds good. I've already had a brief look at NSFetchedResultsController but must have forgot about it. With the callback, where would you store the user information though? I'd need to make the information available throughout the app. So I guess you would create an User object (singleton or not) and store the fetched objects properties on the User object?

Comment: You could do it as a singleton, but you can also just create a new fetchedResultsController for all objects that care to monitor it.  The context has an object cache and will likely not result in a fetch to the store.  If you find later that you are having performance issue then you can change it to a singleton. But to start with that seem to me to be over-optimizing.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a very elegant solution in my opinion.
From the beginning I was using a Singleton called `sharedCoreDataManager`, I added a property `backgroundContext` that is initialized like so

```
self.backgroundContext = _persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext;
_backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
_backgroundContext.retainsRegisteredObjects = YES;
```

and is retained by `sharedCoreDataManager`. I am using this context to perform any tasks. Through calling `_backgroundContext.retainsRegisteredObjects` my NSManagedObject is retained by the `backgroundContext`, which is itself (like I said) retained by my Singleton `sharedCoreDataManager`.

I think this is an elegant solution as I can access the ManagedObject threadsafe from the background anytime. I also won't need any extra class that holds the user information on top. And on top of that I can easily edit the user information at anytime and then call `save()` on my `backgroundContext` if needed.

Maybe I am going to add it as a child to my viewContext in the future, I'll evaluate the performance and eventually update this answer.

**You are still welcome to propose a better solution or discuss this topic.**